# Вывод HTML тегов из БД в Joomla

Tags: joomla, html

Здравствуйте.
В таблице модулей Джумлы есть поле с текстом в котором содержится ещё и HTML теги. При выводе этого поля теги проглатываются. Как можно это изменить?
Спасибо.

Comment: А можете описать по подробнее что за поле что за теги?

Comment: к примеру тег <a>

Comment: Это "защита от вставки тегов" иначе каждый мог бы вставить свои теги например <script/> надо почитать мануал там наверно есть про это может ктото ответит вам я знаю лиш то что написал :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Сайт -> Пользователи -> Administrator -> Редактор пользователя установить как` **Editor - No Editor**

Javascript, html все работает!